# Is there a built-in way to load data augmentation configs from a file in TensorFlow/Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I'm looking for something like:

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.load_and_parse_data_aug_from_config("my_data_aug.yaml")
```

Then I can use it however I want, such as:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Conv2D(...
])
```

This based on coming from [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2), where I saved my data augmentation steps in a configuration file and found that process much easier to track and record my experiments.

Comment: What about this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation?hl=en Option 1: Make the preprocessing layers part of your model.

Comment: That doesn't load the data augmentation config from a separate file. They're written directly into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it in pure TensorFlow/Keras, but if you're using [albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/), you can do it like so:

```
import albumentations as A
transform = A.Compose([
    A.RandomCrop(768, 768),
    A.OneOf([
        A.RGBShift(), 
        A.HueSaturationValue()
    ]),
])
A.save(transform, '/tmp/transform.json')
```

Then load it like so:

```
loaded_transform = A.load('/tmp/transform.json')
```

See [this tutorial](https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/serialization/) for more details.